# Можно ли при работе с эксель файлом из python экспортировать отдельный лист как pdf?

Tags: python, excel, pdf

есть следующая задача:

На входе питон получает определенные данные, которые вносит в первый лист экселя, во втором листе по определенным правилам генерируется готовая таблица. Вот эту таблицу из второго листа нужно сохранить отдельным файлом как pdf. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlrd
from fpdf import FPDF #python -m pip install fpdf 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Путь к файлу.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(1) #лист из книги excel по индексу

collection = [] #массив значений с листа 2

for i in range(sh.nrows):
    r = sh.row_values(i)
    collection.append(r) #записываем каждую строку листа 2 в массив
    print(r)

spacing = 1

pdf = FPDF() #создаем файл PDF
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.add_page()

col_width = pdf.w / 4.5
row_height = pdf.font_size
for row in collection:
    for item in row:
        pdf.cell(col_width, row_height*spacing, txt=str(item), border=1)
    pdf.ln(row_height*spacing)

pdf.output(r'Путь и название нового файла.pdf')
```

Чтобы в строке `pdf.cell(col_width, row_height*spacing, txt=str(item), border=1)` не возникало проблем с кодировками кириллицы и остальных символов - лучше заранее обрабатывать значения из Эксельки.

Comment: Спасибо, как я понял такой способ сохраняет построчно второй лист, создает PDF и заполняет его из массива? Сработает ли это если второй лист создает изображения по правилам используя переменные первого листа и заготовки изображений из третьего?

Comment: Если у вас много инфы разного вида нужно записать в PDF - лучше почитайте о самой библиотеке pyFPDF, там много примеров. https://python-scripts.com/create-pdf-pyfpdf

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить из  самого EXCEL я надеюсь?
Тогда находясь на листе делаем "сохранить как" в окошке "тип файла" выбираем PDF. Задаем имя и сохраняем.